# Having issues with token refresh and logout functionality using the github repo for Angular and OneLogin OIDC

Tags: angular, openid-connect, refresh-token, onelogin

I cloned the example repo at https://github.com/onelogin/onelogin-oidc-angular and changed the config details to point to my Onelogin instance. However, I am having a few issues getting the logout and automatic token renewal functionalities to work out of the box.

For the logout functionality, I called the `signoutRedirect` function from the `oidc-client.js` library. I also made sure that the post logout redirect URI is set in the Auth service. `post_logout_redirect_uri: 'http://localhost:4200/logout'`
However, when I trigger the logout functionality, i notice it does clear the session storage (where the tokens and other metadata are stored by default), but it also logs a console error message and does not redirect to the logout route as configured above.

The error message is: `Error: no end session endpoint`. Please note that, the provided authority field value in the `auth.service.ts` file in the repo (`https://openid-connect.onelogin-shadow01.com/oidc`) did not work for us, so we switched it to: `https://xxx.onelogin.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

As per the supporting blog provided for instructions on how to test the silent auto token renewal (https://www.scottbrady91.com/OpenID-Connect/Silent-Refresh-Refreshing-Access-Tokens-when-using-the-Implicit-Flow), I kept the network tab open to see if requests are automatically sent to renew the token. I did see the auth endpoint being called close to the token expiration (1 hr), however, the id tokens + metadata stored in the session storage by default does not get updated.

Is there another step we are missing to manually adjust the token upon renewal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in oidc-client.js there is an event **addUserLoaded**, you have to listen to it na dthat will help you to load and update the new user with metadata

```
this._userManager.events.addUserLoaded((args) => {
  this._userManager.getUser().then((user) => {
    this._user = user;
    console.log(user);
  });
});
```

you can display it's content and see what does your identity provider send in return,
here is my silent-refresh html file content

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/oidc-client/1.5.1/oidc-client.min.js"></script>

<script>
   var config = {
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
   };
   new Oidc.UserManager(config).signinSilentCallback()
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Hey Fateh, thanks for your comment! I was just reading your post in another SO thread. Just confirming though in my script (silent-refresh.html), I import the oidc client as follows: `<script src="assets/oidc-client.min.js"></script>`.

How do you get access to the usermanager object there? In the github repo they mention -> `new Oidc.UserManager()`. So basically will it be `new Oidc.UserManager().events.addUserLoaded(...)` ? Thanks!